# Checking multiple values of nodes in xml from xslt and displaying in html

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file which i got by exporting a database. now i need to show the xml data in html page as a table. to do so, i have to check the corresponding values for a particular data in the XML file from an XSLT file. since my database is a bit complicated, i am facing difficulties in checking the multiple values of differnt nodes and selecting a corresponding values from another node of the xml file. e.g. i have the following xml data-

```
   <?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='myXSL.xsl'?>

<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name1>
    <names>
      <id>5</id>
      <class>space</class>
      <from>Germany</from>      
      <fm>
        <id>9</id>
        <names>5</names>
        <name>Vienna</name>        
      </fm>
      <fm>
        <id>10</id>
        <names>5</names>
        <name>Prague</name>        
      </fm>
    </names>    
  </name1>
  <FFrom>    
    <effect>
      <id>11</id>
      <DVV>1</DVV>
      <SAT>0</SAT>
      <DDCC>0</DDCC>      
      <name>SAA Name</name>      
    </effect>    
    <effect>
      <id>23</id>
      <DVV>0</DVV>
      <SAT>0</SAT>
      <DDCC>1</DDCC>      
      <name>SAA Name2</name>      
    </effect>
  </FFrom>  
  <name2>
    <newNames>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>VSSS Name</name>
      <route1>
        <id>5</id>
        <identifyer>C</identifyer>
        <function>abc</function>
        <names>4</names>
        <naviagtes2>
          <id>9</id>
          <fm>7</fm>
          <effect>2</effect>          
        </naviagtes2>
        <naviagtes2>
          <id>10</id>
          <fm>8</fm>
          <effect>5</effect>         
        </naviagtes2>
      </route1>  
    </newNames>
    <newNames>
      <id>6</id>
      <name>VEE Name</name>
      <route1>
        <id>18</id>
        <identifyer>C0</identifyer>
        <function>abc</function>
        <names>5</names>
        <naviagtes2>
          <id>68</id>
          <fm>9</fm>
          <effect>11</effect>          
        </naviagtes2>
        <naviagtes2>
          <id>69</id>
          <fm>10</fm>
          <effect>7</effect>          
        </naviagtes2>
      </route1>       
    </newNames>
  </name2>
</root>
```

I used the following xslt codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

 <html>

 <head><title>title</title>
 <style type="text/css">

body {
    font: 10px Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
tr.header2 {
    font-style:italic;
}
tr.newNames{
    background-color:#6495ED;
    margin-top:4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><h1><xsl:value-of select="Title" /></h1>
 <table width="800px" class="table" cellspacing="0px"> 
 <xsl:for-each select="root/name2/newNames"> 
  <tr class="newNames"><td colspan="12">
  <b>NNavigate:</b> <xsl:value-of select="name"/><br/>
  <b>NMNaviagate:</b> <xsl:value-of select="route1/function"/>
  </td></tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/root/name1/names">
    <tr class="names"><td colspan="12">
    <b> CClass: </b><xsl:value-of select="class" />
    <b> FFrom: </b><xsl:value-of select="from" />   
    </td></tr>  
        <tr class="header2">
            <td>Route</td>
            <td>From</td>
            <td align="center">SA</td>
            <td align="center">DB</td>

        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="fm">
        <tr>
            <td class=""><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>                
            <td class=""><xsl:value-of select="/root/FFrom/effect/name" /></td>
            <td class=""><xsl:value-of select="/root/FFrom/effect/SAT" /></td>
            <td class=""><xsl:value-of select="/root/FFrom/effect/DVV" /></td>              
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am stuck in the following point. 
if you notice there are fm nodes, effect nodes and naviagtes2 nodes. 
in my html page, there will be a table where values of first column come from fm nodes (root/name1/names/fm/name) and values of second column come from effect nodes (root/FFrom/effect/name). in the naviagtes2 nodes, there are fm and effect elements which are equivalent to fm/id and effect/id. that is, naviagtes2 nodes are used to check which values of effect/name will be against fm/name in the table. conditions are like following

```
root/name1/names/fm/name against root/FFrom/effect/name if 
root/name1/names/fm/id = root/name2/newNames/route1/naviagtes2/fm  and 
root/FFrom/effect/id = root/name2/newNames/route1/naviagtes2/effect
```

i am new in XSLT programming. Could anyone give me any clue please how to solve that in XSLT ?

Comment: You're more likely to get useful responses and explanations if you show the XSLT that's not working right.  Simplification in the service of a shorter working example reduced to essentials is a good thing, too.

Comment: Add in a valid XSLT (not just snippets) so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Your XML code is invalid and your XSLT is incomplete. Please post code that would enable us to reproduce the problem by copying it and running it without modification.

Comment: @ michael.hor257k actually, it is not appropriate for me to post the original codes. i just need the hints how this query will work. i have explained the essential part of my problem. could you please help me for it ?

Comment: "*it is not appropriate for me to post the original codes.*" I don't care if it's original or fake. I do care about wasting my time correcting your code in order to make it run. Only by running it and reproducing the problem I can suggest how to fix it. Note also that you say "it shows wrong values" - but you should also say what the "right" values are.

Comment: @michael.hor257k , ok i am giving the complete code here again. please help me to fix it.

Comment: That is progress. Now, if you could just explain what needs to be added in plain human language instead of incomprehensible pseudo-code, perhaps we could finish this.

Answer (score 0):

> in the naviagtes2 nodes, there are fm and effect elements which are
>   equivalent to fm/id and effect/id. that is, naviagtes2 nodes are used
>   to check which values of effect/name will be against fm/name in the
>   table.

I am afraid I still don't understand  your question, but in an effort of moving this forward, I'll take a stab (in the dark?) at it.

The following stylesheet uses **keys** to link each naviagtes2 node to the fm and effect elements whose ids are listed in the naviagtes2 node. Thus each naviagtes2 node creates a {fm,effect} "pair" and these pairs are listed in the resulting table, along with the values fetched from the paired elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fm" match="name1/names/fm" use="id" />
<xsl:key name="effect" match="FFrom/effect" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1" > 
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>fm id</th>
            <th>effect id</th>
            <th>fm name</th>
            <th>effect name</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/name2/newNames/route1/naviagtes2"> 
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="id" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="fm" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="effect" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="key('fm', fm)/name" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="key('effect', effect)/name" /></td>
            </tr>       
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>fm id</th>
      <th>effect id</th>
      <th>fm name</th>
      <th>effect name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>68</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Vienna</td>
      <td>SAA Name</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>69</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Prague</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

which in HTML would be rendered as:

[image]

Hopefully this gets you closer to your goal.

Comment: thanks a lot. you got my point, and partially solved my problem. now fm name and effect name are consistent.but you used only one loop and ignored other loops that i mentioned in my XSLT codes. that'S why it is showing all values in each iteration :(

Comment: @Cracker You will have to either find a way to incorporate this into what you have, or make your question clearer. Note that despite comments going back and forth for more than a week(!) now, you still haven't posted the expected result. There's a limit to the time and patience I am willing to put into this.